# No "DRY" (don't repeat yourself) principle in Contoso University MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dry

I am following this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I realize that CRUD is using 4 forms. Example, for "Departments", if I want to remove the budget column, I have to remove it in four places:

- Delete.cshtml
- Details.cshtml
- Create.cshtml
- Edit.cshtml

And the layout for these four forms are quite similar right? Can we just use one form to do the CRUD instead? For web forms, I can do it in one web form. Using the session user roles, I don't the aspx page. Can we do the same for MVC?

The solution is change it at the controller and to re-generate all the CRUD using scaffolding? But if that is the case, then all my customized CSS in CRUD has to be added again?

Regards, Steve

Comment: A `Create` and `Edit` view are both modifying data and therefore you should be using a view model anyway (and could possibly be using the same view model, or at least a common base view model). A details view is not for editing and wont have a form or form controls so wont have any resemblance to the `Create` and `Edit` views. And why would you be showing the 'Budget' property in a `Delete` view (and your `Delete()` method could simply be called from your `Details` view.

Comment: But for this sample project, the delete page does have its own view. Print screen - http://demo.findingsteve.net/contoso1.jpg